# Visual Studio: Designer crashed and now it is gone

Tags: visual-studio

a coupple days ago, out of the blue I got a message from VS saying: XAML Designer Version xy crashed. Do you want to stop the plug in?

I said yes.
Now, this is my xml page:

[image]

The Designer is completely gone. Usually, there would be atab on the left corner to go to the designer but even restarts didnt solve the issue. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own question BUT: Extras- Extensions and UPdates - Android Designer was deactivated there. Hitting activitate solved that obviously. Thanks go.